# Docker open ports in iptables (rabbitmq)

Tags: iptables, docker, rabbitmq

- I'm having a docker image based on `rabbitmq`.
- Nothing in my Dockerfile specifies anything about ports.
- I bind the usual rabbitmq ports (5671, 5672 and 15672) to my custom ports by running my instance as follows:

  `docker run -d -p $someport:5671 -p 127.0.0.1::5672 -p $somemgtport:15672 myimage`
- There is nothing in my iptables INPUT chain, and the FORWARD chain is filled with the usual docker stuff.

#### The problem

When `$somemgtport` is different from `15672` I can't access to it (the rabbitmq management interface via HTTP) from the outside world.

But it seems that I used the `-p` flag correctly because `curl https://localhost:$somemgtport` works as expected (as well as the amqp calls to $someport).

When running, the iptables DOCKER chain is the following:

```
Chain DOCKER (1 references)
 target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !docker0 docker0  anywhere             xyz  tcp dpt:15672
 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !docker0 docker0  anywhere             xyz  tcp dpt:5671
 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !docker0 docker0  anywhere             xyz  tcp dpt:amqp
```

So it doesn't open the ports $someport and $somemgtport but rather the ports that are correspond to the "inside" of the container: 5671 and 15672 (the ones from rabbitmq).

=> it seems to me that it's doing exactly the contrary to what I would expect...!

What did I do wrong with the `docker run` command?

NB: I want other ports than the default ones because I'm running 2 instances of rabbitmq on the same machine.

---

Update - Here's a partial output of `netstat -pln` (with `someport=55001` and `somemgtport=65002`):

```
tcp6       0      0 :::55001                :::*                    LISTEN      29613/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::65002                :::*                    LISTEN      29622/docker-proxy
```

`netstat -pln | grep 15672` has no output

Comment: Can you share the output of `netstat -pln | grep 15672` inside the container?

Answer (score 1):

**Deprecation Notice**: That question is outdated, whatever might have created it at the time doesn't exist anymore. Docker stopped using iptables (to achieve port redirection) a long time ago, the network layer was rewritten from scratch at least twice since the question was posted.